# Apache 2 Sub-Domains to 1 Server Redirect

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

I am trying to create two redirects from another server (stream.kups.net and archive.kups.net) to point to one server lxap05.pugetsound.edu, but different locations on this server. I'm getting some weird results from Apache and I was wondering if you could take a look at my virtualhost configuration

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName stream.kups.net
Redirect / http://lxap05.pugetsound.edu:8000/KUPS-iTunes.m3u
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName archive.kups.net
Redirect / http://lxap05.pugetsound.edu/radio_archive/index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

stream.kups.net goes to the correct location, but archive.kups.net combines the stream url and the archive url together so I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "combines the stream url and the archive url together" - what URL do you end up with?

Comment: http://lxap05.pugetsound.edu:8000/KUPS-iTunes.m3uradio_archive/index.html